# Demon fighting magician

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

Looking for the title of a YA series, I think over 5 books long. Published somewhere in 2000-2010 possibly.

The protagonist is a normal teenager, who learns he can do magic. I remember at one point there is some mentor figure who is taking him to different places/dimensions, maybe as a learning exercise in teleportation.

One of the locations they go to is so bright, despite shielding his eyes (with his hands) they are destroyed. And he must reconstruct them with magic, and shield himself with magic. It happens again but he finds the rebuilding process much easier/quicker.

I think his new 'magic' eyes can also see something new now as well, like hidden traps or leftover magic.

The whole plot revolved him learning to control magic and fight off demons or one particular demon who had minions.

Comment: The Demonata by Darren Shan? Kernel's eyes get destroyed and reformed at one point (don't have the book so can't verify the context), and it's all about fighting demons and traveling between dimensions. Lord Loss is the demon with the minions.

Comment: I wondered about that, but Kernel's eyes are punctured by a demon shaped like a scorpion (in book 9 - Dark Calling) not destroyed by a bright light.

Comment: I believe he also loses them to lava in The Demon Thief, but again, that's not quite what OP described. The "seeing magic" part is very Kernel, though.

Comment: Oh yes, he falls into a river of molten lava! Careless really :-)